# Is there a compare function for file name sorting?

Tags: delphi, file, sorting, delphi-xe2, windows-explorer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get the sort order in Delphi as in Windows Explorer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5134712/how-to-get-the-sort-order-in-delphi-as-in-windows-explorer)

I'm looking for a function that would compare (for file sorting) exactly like Windows Explorer does. Now I'm using `CompareText` function, but it results in the following:

```
---------  /\  ---------
 AFile
 BFile
 _XFile
-----------------------
```

And Windows Explorer sort the same items this way (that's what I want to get):

```
---------  /\  ---------
 _XFile
 AFile
 BFile
-----------------------
```

Is there a function for this kind of comparing or should I handle this by my own ?

Thanks!

Comment: RRUZ, my fault, sorry. I have voted to close. Next time I will check the proposed matches more attentively. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Windows Explorer uses [`StrCmpLogicalW`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759947.aspx) to compare file names. The RTL/VCL does not declare this function so you need to do it yourself.

```
function StrCmpLogicalW(psz1, psz2: PWideChar): Integer; stdcall;
    external 'shlwapi.dll';
```

Comment: Thanks! I was looking for where this function is defined, but found only in Winapi.ShlObj note `dont use StrCmpLogical() instead use default CompareString()`

Comment: @Martin: Of course you can use this function even if it is not declared in any `.pas` file.

Comment: @Martin I've included all you need to call the function now

Comment: @Martin The declaration you found, `REST_NOSTRCMPLOGICAL` is a flag that can be used to make Explorer work in legacy pre-XP mode when it did use `CompareString`. I think this is as close as there is to official confirmation that Explorer uses `StrCmpLogicalW`!

Comment: I see and tested it already, works as I wanted. Thanks!