# How to sort list by first number?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I have a huge list of users and every user has it's id , but it id numbers are messed up so if anyone can show me how can I sort users by numbers , every value has this form

```
1:Stackoverflow
or
145000:Google
```

If I do that manually I think I will lose my mind since tehere are more than 700000 records.Thanks for your time and help....

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5134712/how-to-get-the-sort-order-in-delphi-as-in-windows-explorer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Extract the number like this:

```
function ID(const str: string): Integer;
var
  p: Integer;
begin
  p := Pos(':', str);
  if p=0 then
    raise Exception.CreateFmt('Invalid string format: %s', [str]);
  Result := StrToInt(Copy(str, 1, p-1));
end;
```

Once you can extract the ID as an integer you can then write a compare function. Like this:

```
function CompareIDs(List: TStringList; Index1, Index2: Integer): Integer;
begin
  Result := CompareValue(
    ID(List[Index1]), 
    ID(List[Index2])
  );
end;
```

[`CompareValue`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Math.CompareValue) is an RTL function that returns -1, 0 or 1 depending on the relative values of the two operands.

Feed these building blocks into [`TStringList.CustomSort`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TStringList.CustomSort) and your job is done.

```
MyStringList.CustomSort(CompareIDs);
```

Comment: Result = ValueCompare( ID1, ID2);

Comment: @Marck You mean `CompareValue` I think. I agree it's better to use built in routines and I was not aware of it. I will update the answer.