# Delphi - sorting TStringList with mixed values - integer and string

Tags: sorting, delphi

I have a little problem with sorting TStringList with mixed values. Its something like:

> 7567533575 Joe
>   1543779744 Ann
>   9757462323 Jack
>   6999966578 Stef

and I need to sort this list to see:

> 1543779744 Ann
>   6999966578 Stef
>   7567533575 Joe
>   9757462323 Jack

I can do this with about 3x for loops, with string trim and one array. But it is very lame solution... I guess, someone have best code for this. I dont understand CustomSort... ehh. Please, help me.

- I use Delphi 10.

Comment: That looks like a pretty forward, simple string sorting to me. What am I missing here?

Comment: What exactly are you having problems with? What have you tried and why did it not work as you wished?

Comment: What happens when you have two rows with the same number but different names? You have not actually defined an order yet?

Comment: Are all of the numbers exactly 10 digits?

Comment: Yeap, as you see

Comment: Which is first : `1543779744 Ann` or `1543779744 Anna`?

Comment: Your problem is hopelessly underspecified, so I don't know whether this will help you. However, in general one would want to use [natural sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_sort_order) for sorting "mixed values", and a Google search for "delphi natural sort" gives you [an old Delphi question here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5134712/how-to-get-the-sort-order-in-delphi-as-in-windows-explorer) as the first result.

Answer (score 5):

Using `CustomSort()` is the correct solution. Simply pass it a function that parses and compares 2 input strings, returning:

- < 0 if the 1st string should appear before the 2nd string.
- 0 if the 2 strings are "equal" and either string can appear before the other.
- > 0 if the 2nd string should appear before the 1st string.

```
function MySortFunc(List: TStringList; Index1, Index2: Integer): Integer;
var
  Value1, Value2: Int64;
  S: string;
begin
  S := List[Index1];
  Value1 := StrToInt64(Copy(S, 1, Pos(' ', S)-1));
  S := List[Index2];
  Value2 := StrToInt64(Copy(S, 1, Pos(' ', S)-1));
  if Value1 < Value2 then
    Result := -1
  else if Value2 < Value1 then
    Result := 1
  else
    Result := 0;
end;

MyStringList.CustomSort(MySortFunc);
```

Comment: The arithmetic could overflow. Better to use inequality operators.

Comment: I prefer using `CompareValue` from `System.Math`. One can use the result directly as the return value of the sort function.