List(of String) Not Sorting Numerically with IComparer
I have a list of strings that are sorting this way.  I want them sorted normally. I have implemented an IComparer, but it's not working.
Slide1.jpg
Slide10.jpg
Slide11.jpg
Slide12.jpg
Slide2.jpg
Slide3.jpg

I am using the comparer like this
 Dim files = Directory.GetFiles("c:\PowerPoint\Images", "*.jpg", SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList()
 files.Sort(New NaturalComparer(True))


Public Class NaturalComparer
  Implements IComparer(Of String)
  Private _pos As Integer
  Private ReadOnly _order As Integer

  Public Sub New(Optional Ascending As Boolean = True)
    _order = If(Ascending, 1, -1)
  End Sub

  Private Shared Function RegexSplit(ByVal s As String) As String()
    Return Regex.Split(s, "(\d+) Then", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
  End Function

  Private Shared Function GetEmptyStrings() As Predicate(Of String)
    Return Function(s) String.IsNullOrEmpty(s)
  End Function

  Public Function Compare(x As String, y As String) As Integer Implements IComparer(Of String).Compare
    Dim left As New List(Of String)(RegexSplit(x))
    Dim right As New List(Of String)(RegexSplit(y))

    left.RemoveAll(GetEmptyStrings())
    right.RemoveAll(GetEmptyStrings())

    _pos = 0
    For Each x In left
        If y.Count > _pos Then
            If Not Decimal.TryParse(x, Nothing) AndAlso Not Decimal.TryParse(right(_pos), Nothing) Then
                Dim result As Integer = String.Compare(x, right(_pos), True)
                If result <> 0 Then
                    Return result * _order
                Else
                    _pos += 1
                End If
            ElseIf Decimal.TryParse(x, Nothing) AndAlso Not Decimal.TryParse(right(_pos), Nothing) Then
                Return -1 * _order
            ElseIf Not Decimal.TryParse(x, Nothing) AndAlso Decimal.TryParse(right(_pos), Nothing) Then
                Return 1 * _order
            Else
                Dim result = Decimal.Compare(Decimal.Parse(x), Decimal.Parse(right(_pos)))
                If result = 0 Then
                    _pos += 1
                Else
                    Return result * _order
                End If
            End If
        Else
            Return -1 * _order
        End If
    Next

    Return _order
  End Function

End Class

Not really sure where this is going wrong. I felt like this worked at some point. Any help on this would be helpful. I am just learning this stuff so if you can give a bit more detail that would be helpful.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/70633729/14171304

This is actually a tricky algorithm you are trying to implement. It will be easier if you can pad the numbers with leading zeroes.

Well... Your code is almost perfect. Only small improvements were needed in a Compare function.
Public Class NaturalComparer 
Implements IComparer(Of String)
Private _pos As Integer
Private ReadOnly _order As Integer

    Public Sub New(Optional Ascending As Boolean = True)
        _order = If(Ascending, 1, -1)
    End Sub

    Private Shared Function RegexSplit(ByVal s As String) As String()
        Return Regex.Split(s, "(\d+)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
    End Function

    Private Shared Function GetEmptyStrings() As Predicate(Of String)
        Return Function(s) String.IsNullOrEmpty(s)
    End Function
    
    Public Function Compare(x As String, y As String) As Integer Implements IComparer(Of String).Compare
        Dim left As New List(Of String)(RegexSplit(x))
        Dim right As New List(Of String)(RegexSplit(y))

        left.RemoveAll(GetEmptyStrings())
        right.RemoveAll(GetEmptyStrings())

        _pos = 0
        For Each x In left
            If y.Count > _pos Then
                If Not Integer.TryParse(x, Nothing) AndAlso Not Integer.TryParse(right(_pos), Nothing) Then
                    Dim result As Integer = String.Compare(x, right(_pos), True)
                    If result <> 0 Then
                        Return result * _order
                    Else
                        _pos += 1
                    End If
                ElseIf Integer.TryParse(x, Nothing) AndAlso Not Integer.TryParse(right(_pos), Nothing) Then
                    Return -1 * _order
                ElseIf Not Integer.TryParse(x, Nothing) AndAlso Integer.TryParse(right(_pos), Nothing) Then
                    Return 1 * _order
                Else
                    Dim result = Decimal.Compare(Integer.Parse(x), Integer.Parse(right(_pos)))
                    If result = 0 Then
                        _pos += 1
                    Else
                        Return result * _order
                    End If
                End If
            Else
                Return -1 * _order
            End If
        Next

        Return _order
    End Function
End Class

I tested it with below code:
Dim slides As List(Of String) = New List(Of String) From {"Slide1.jpg", "Slide10.jpg", "Slide11.jpg", "Slide12.jpg", "Slide2.jpg", "Picture3.jpg"}
slides.Sort(New NaturalComparer(True))

Result:

Picture3.jpg
Slide1.jpg
Slide2.jpg
Slide10.jpg
Slide11.jpg
Slide12.jpg


Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Public NotInheritable Class NaturalStringSorter : Implements IComparer(Of String)

    <DllImport("shlwapi.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode)>
    Private Shared Function StrCmpLogicalW(s1 As String, s2 As String) As Integer : End Function

    Private ReadOnly _order As Integer

    Public Sub New(Optional Ascending As Boolean = True)
        _order = If(Ascending, 1, -1)
    End Sub

    Public Function Compare(s1 As String, s2 As String) As Integer Implements IComparer(Of String).Compare
        Return _order * StrCmpLogicalW(s1, s2)
    End Function

End Class

