Delphi sorting Strings containing text and numbers



I am trying to sort a list of strings with text and numbers:
Normal text sorting goes like:
But I want:




Team 1
Team 1
Team 1


Team 2
Team 10
Team 2


Team 10
Team 12
Team 10


Team 12
Team 2
Team 12


Team 20
Team 20
Team 20


Team 21
Team 21
Team 21



These are user-entered strings, could also be T101, T102, T301 etc. (these could be easier). I don't want to try to reinvent the wheel, but I have not been able to find a Pascal example which does the job.
More details: The items I need to sort are in fact in a TObjectList, which has to be sorted by TSARPanel.RefName:
TSARPanel = class(TObject)
  ...
  RefName: String;
  ...
end;

TSARPanelList = class(TObjectList)
private
  function GetRecord(AIndex: Integer): TSARPanel;
  procedure SetRecord(AIndex: Integer; const AValue: TSARPanel);
public
  property Items[AIndex: Integer]: TSARPanel read GetRecord write SetRecord; default;
  ...
end;

Based on Remy's example, how do I manage to convert it into a TArray<String> based sort?

To post a question here, you are required to "Show what you’ve tried and tell us what you found (on this site or elsewhere) and why it didn’t meet your needs. You can get better answers when you provide research."  Have you tried doing it yourself?

Search for 'natural sort', for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5134712/how-to-get-the-sort-order-in-delphi-as-in-windows-explorer

Use generics and write your own StringComparer https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.Generics.Defaults.TStringComparer

If you are on a more recent Delphi version, you can make use of TStringHelper.Compare() and the coDigitAsNumbers option. This example is using Delphi 12:
uses
  System.SysUtils,
  System.Generics.Collections,
  System.Generics.Defaults;

procedure Main;
begin
  var arr := TArray<string>.Create('Team 1', 'Team 10', 'Team 12', 'Team 2', 'Team 20', 'Team 21');
  TArray.Sort<string>(arr, TDelegatedComparer<string>.Create(
    function(const Left, Right: string): Integer
    begin
      Result := string.Compare(Left, Right, [coDigitAsNumbers]);
    end
    ));
  for var S in arr do
    Writeln(S);
end;

Update:
Based on your question update, a solution for your case could be like this:
  SARPanelList.SortList(
    function (Item1, Item2: Pointer): Integer
    begin
      Result := string.Compare(TSARPanel(Item1).RefName, TSARPanel(Item2).RefName);
    end
  );


Just note that coDigitAsNumbers is supported only on Windows 7 and later.

Remy, if you could give me a hand with integrating your example with the actual Objectlist I have to sort. I tried but I cannot get my head around it how to mesh your code with my Objectlist which includes the string on which it has to be sorted... I updated my question.

Uwe, yes already done this, but I now have to link it to this TArray based system from Remy, and I cannot seem to grab how to do that.

The TArray.Sort is just an example how to sort strings in an array. As you are working with an TObjectList, you can use the Sort or SortList method providing a suitable comparer. You should be fine with that and there is no need to involve TArray in your case.

Thanks Uwe, that TArray threw me completely off. I now have a working solution based on Remy's principle. The key is in this "coDigitAsNumbers" option...

@BartKindt You mean Uwe's principle, not mine.

Ages ago I used to modify texts before comparing them to make them sort in a way one mostly wants to sort it, f.e. May 10, 2006 should sort after May 9, 2006. The inefficiency in here is that either you'd have to modify all the texts anew per comparison, or you need to do it once and store all those, too, for comparison reasons. And the text modification itself could be a performance killer for large amounts.
// Modify texts to make them naturally comparable with numbers in it,
// so original text "May 10, 2006" would sort AFTER "May 9, 2006".
procedure ExtendNumbers( var sText: String );
var
  iPos,  // Character of text we're inspecting in loop.
  iCount: Integer;  // Amount of digits we found in a row.
begin
  iCount:= 0;
  // Inspect text from end to start, because we will insert text.
  for iPos:= Length( sText ) downto 1 do begin
    if sText[iPos] in ['0'.. '9'] then begin  // Is it a digit?
      Inc( iCount );  // One more digit that we found.
    end else  // This character is no digit (anymore).
    if iCount<> 0 then begin  // Have we found digits so far?
      // Make the amount of found digits at max 21 digits by preceeding
      // them with zeroes. We're already at a non-digit characters, so
      // we need to insert it one character later. 21 because that is
      // the maximum of digits for Int64.
      Insert( StringOfChar( '0', 21- iCount ), sText, iPos+ 1 );
      iCount:= 0;  // Reset amount of found digits.
    end;
  end;

  // Should the text start with a digit/number, also fill that number up to 21 digits.
  if iCount<> 0 then Insert( StringOfChar( '0', 21- iCount ), sText, 1 );
end;

The benefit of this approach is: it's unbound to a platform or any operating system version. However, it only works for Arabic/ASCII numerals and not all numerals in Unicode/the world.

I actually question the selected use case here. If one wants May 10, 2006 sorted after May 9, 2006, one probably also wants May 10, 2005 sorted before May 9, 2006 as well as May 9, 2006 sorted before June 9, 2006.

@UweRaabe Yes, that's not the best example on my side - I should have left out the year.

This does the trick, based on Remy's example with "coDigitAsNumbers"
function ComparePanels(Item1, Item2: Pointer):integer;
begin
  result := string.Compare(TSARPanel(Item1).RefName, TSARPanel(Item2).RefName, [coDigitAsNumbers]);
end;


The example belongs to Uwe Raabe, not me. And really, this answer is not needed since it is just repeating Uwe's answer. Better to give credit where it is due and accept his answer instead.
